# Intuition for categorical fibrations?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, intuition

I think I have a pretty good *intuitive* understanding of most types of [fibrations of quasicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fibrations+of+quasi-categories):

- a (trivial) Kan fibration is a bundle of (contractible) spaces with equivalent fibers,
- a left/right fibration is a bundle of spaces with covariant/contravariant functors between fibers,
- a (co)Cartesian fibration is the same as left/right but now the fibers are $\infty$-categories,
- an inner fibration is bundle of $\infty$-categories with correspondences between fibers.

One major exception is the class of categorical fibrations. I know they are the fibrations in the Joyal model structure on sSet but that description isn't very illuminating to me. I feel this is problematic since categorical fibrations are central to the theory of $\infty$-operads, which I am trying to learn at the moment.

What would be the best way to describe categorical fibrations in a similarly intuitive way?

Comment: I would disagree with your characterization of an inner fibration: bundles of ∞-categories with correspondences are better represented by flat fibrations (you can find them treated in appendix B in HA). Inner fibrations, like categorical fibrations, are not particularly meaningful on their own, they are just a convenient point-set condition which can always be enforced up to homotopy.

Comment: That description came from the paragraph following HTT.2.3.1.5. I don't know much about flat inner fibrations, but would it be fair to say the difference is that flatness allows you to compose correspondences, which you couldn't do otherwise?

Comment: According to [Barwick and Shah](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04343), just as a flat categorical fibration $E \to B$ corresponds to a 2-functor $B \to Corr$, an isofibration $E \to B$ corresponds to some kind of _lax_ 2-functor $B \to Corr$, where $Corr$ is the 2-category whose objects are categories and 1-morphisms are correspondences / profunctors / distributors / bimodules. A proof is expected to appear in work of Peter Haine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Categorical fibrations are not particularly meaningful in their own right. Luckily, there is a characterization in the most interesting case, of categorical fibrations $p:Q\to R$ between quasicategories. Namely such a map $p$ is nothing more than an inner fibration and an *isofibration*, that is, it is weakly orthogonal to the inclusion of either endpoint into $E[1]$, the nerve of the isomorphism category. Alternative characterizations are that the restriction of $p$ to the cores is a Kan fibration, which might be the most intuitive description, or that $p$ induces an isofibration on homotopy categories. This approach to categorical fibrations is used throughout Riehl and Verity's work and can also be found in Rezk's notes "Stuff about Quasicategories."

It may be worth remarking here that every functor of $\infty$-categories is equivalent to an inner fibration with the same codomain, so that the most invariant and conceptual way of thinking about a categorical fibration may be simply as an isofibration, full stop. This is in close analogy to the canonical model structure on the category of small categories.